# maximizing print size over 300dpi

Tags: portrait, printing, canon-60d

i usually shot portraits with my 60D and tamron 17-50mm f2.8 using maximum resolution JPEG + RAW @ 5184 x 3456 pixels. after recent photoshoot, i tried to print an 8R using this particular setting and the result were dissapointing in my case (lack of details, seems stretched etc..) i wonder what is the proper way to print a large picture over 16x20" and 20x30"?

thanks

Comment: How are you getting the photo from your camera to the printer? What application are you using if printing from your computer?

Comment: I let some photo printing store to do it for me, and to be frank, speaking about the problem it's gotta be from my end because they have printed many pictures from different photographers and they came out fine.

Comment: at the moment im trying to use smillaenlarger to enlarge the picture hoping that it would restore some of the pixels.

Comment: You can't "restore" pixels with software, it will just perform some more or less clever interpolation. Have a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size

Comment: To clarify my earlier request: What is the workflow involved between the camera and the printer? Do you just pull the memory card out and give it to the printing house? Do you download to your computer and do some editing first? etc.?

Comment: @MichaelClark I did some editing usually just color balance and a little bit of filter and then adjusted its DPI from 72 to 300 then cropped it. that would be all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lack of details, seems stretched

This does suggest a mistake by the printer, as you are implying the aspect ratio was changed ( or the image distorted ? ) just in the print.

Now it is possible that if you used some online service to do this or a kiosk, that you unintentionally changed a setting to make it ignore the aspect ration and simply fit the print to the page, but if you did not then the printer did it.

> it's gotta be from my end because they have printed many pictures from different photographers and they came out fine

This is false reasoning.  Even if they'd never made a mistake before, that does not mean they won't ever make a mistake.

Comment: I see now that it just knock a little sense into my head. I wonder what if I want to print beyond my megapixels? What if  5184 x 3456  which is equal to 137.16 x 91.44 in cm is to be printed to 200 x 100 cm, obviously it would lose some details/color right? 
and do you think the materials where the picture is going to be printed on matter? thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: You don;t loose detail because it's not there to start with.  As a general rule very large prints are viewed from further away and there is no practical problem with resolution.